# Index Match? multiple criteria with search

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find a formula which will return "xx no" in my example below.  I've tried multiple formulas and keep coming up with n/a.

```
=INDEX(C1:C11,MATCH(F2,A1:A11,0),MATCH("xx",C1:C11,0))
{=INDEX(C1:C11,MATCH(F2,A1:A11,0),MATCH("xx",C1:C11,0))}
=INDEX(C1:C11,MATCH(F2,A1:A11,0),MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("xx",C1:C11)),0))
{=INDEX(C1:C11,MATCH(F2,A1:A11,0),MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("xx",C1:C11)),0))}
=INDEX(A1:C11,MATCH(F2,A1:A11,0),MATCH(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("xx",C1:C11)),0))
{=INDEX(A1:C11,MATCH(F2,A1:A11,0),MATCH(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("xx",C1:C11)),0))}
=INDEX(C1:C11,MATCH(F2,A1:A11,0),MATCH(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&"xx"&"*",C1:C11)),0))
{=INDEX(C1:C11,MATCH(F2,A1:A11,0),MATCH(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&"xx"&"*",C1:C11)),0))}
```

[image: Nemesis Image]

Comment: Thank you both so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$11)/(($A$2:$A$11=F2)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F3,$C$2:$C$11)))),1))
```

Or you can use this formula:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$11,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$11=F2)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F3,$C$2:$C$11))),),0))
```

Comment: Please be my best friend

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short array formula to do it:

```
{=INDEX(A2:C8,MATCH(F2&F3,A2:A8&LEFT(C2:C8,LEN(F3)),0),3)}
```

It looks like you already know about array formulas, enter then by pressing Ctrl and Shift as well as Enter